# Herança de Templates não funcionando - Flask

Tags: flask, template

Olá, estou tendo problemas ao usar 'content blocks' ao tentar expandir o conteúdo do meu arquivo HTML base no meu projeto Flask.

Cheguei a ponto de testar a forma mais simples possível de um app Flask, para ver se eu conseguiria debugar oquê está acontecendo, infelizmente não tive sucesso... segue o código.

*server.py*

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

# Executa a aplicação
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

---

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <h2>Primeira Frase</h2>

    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}

  </body>

</html>
```

---

*block-content.html*

```
{% extends "index.html" %}

{% block content %}
Segunda Frase
{% endblock %}
```

Aqui vai um print da [organização do projeto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aF2vv.png)

No final de tudo ao rodar o código somente a 'Primeira Frase' é exibida. Sinto que deve ser um erro muito bobo mas realmente tentei bastante pesquisar para ver se encontrava alguma solução, tentei ao máximo evitar criar uma pergunta mas aqui estou, se alguém puder me ajudar sou muito grato.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É ao contrário, tens de fazer render do block-content. Se quiseres usar o index tens de usar o include.

```
return render_template('block-content.html')
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda :)